# json array format and use with angular 6

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am using a json file to show data.

```
  [{"id":3127,"creationTimestamp":"2018-10-22T13:57:08.000+0000","updateTimestamp":"2018-10-22T13:57:08.000+0000","status":"PENDING"}]
```

The json data above is working well.

My service:

```
    export class SummaryService {
private baseurl='http://localhost:4200/assets/data.json'
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getUsers() : Observable<any>{
   return this.http.get<User[]>(this.baseurl);

  }
}
```

My question is: How do I use the service above with the json format used below?

```
{"InvoiceHeaders":[{"id":3127,"creationTimestamp":"2018-10-22T13:57:08.000+0000","updateTimestamp":"2018-10-22T13:57:08.000+0000","status":"PENDING"}]}
```

My index file:

```
<ul> <li> {{user.id}}  <li>
<li> {{user.creationTimestamp}}</li>
</ul>
```

Please help me to display data using the array above (with "InvoiceHeaders").

Comment: Can you post your HTML too.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `{{this.user.InvoiceHeaders[0].updateTimestamp;}}` because you are sending an array inside of object.

Answer (score -1):

you should return something like this:

```
this.http.get(this.baseurl).map(this.extractData)
```

and this is the extract function:

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body;
    }
```